# Раскройте тайну зависания Kali Linux при выключении

Tags: linux, kali-linux

Почему линукс зависает при выключении?

Я сначала установил его на виртуальную машину, и там всё было супер. Но как только я скачал на флешку, то сразу всё пошло наперекосяк.

Я установил 2019.1, прописывал `sudo apt-get update` и `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.

Если что я на лэптопе с двумя видеокартами (интегр. и дискретной). Вставил флешку и запустил через приоретет загрузки дисков, запустил в live (`persistence`) режиме (если что persistence я настроил). Я пробовал при старте в командной строке grub прописать `x-driver=intel` (выбрать используемую видеокарту).

В итоге вопрос: почему когда систему в том же live режиме на виртуалке работает идеально (`ipv6 link is ready`, выключение, перезагрузка и logout идут нормально), но как только я пересаживаюсь на флешку все эти четыре пункта идут наперекосяк, и что мне с этим делать? (если кто скажет: "Почему тогда на виртуалке не сидишь?", - то по некоторым причинам я не могу в дальнейшем её использовать, так что желательно нужен ответ конкретно на вопрос с флешкой)

Comment: 1. разные драйвера, 2. разные используемые модули. Модель лаптопа в этой формуле крайне критична. Если у вас не совместимость по железу, то стоит глянуть на сайте производителя - может быть наличие открытых драйверов. Была упомянута `intel` - https://01.org/linuxgraphics

Comment: У меня Acer nitro 5 с intel i7 8го поколения, интерг. Intel uhd и дискр. Gtx 1050 ti

Comment: Отключи одну видеокарту в BIOS, конфликт в любом случае будет, рано или поздно. Может это тот случай. Если основная Nvidia, подтяни драйвера проприетарные, они пишут для Linux также.

Comment: https://kali.training/downloads/Kali-Linux-Revealed-1st-edition.pdf в раздел 2 загляни

Comment: Эта проблема требует глубокого анализа: 1. какие программы запущены 2. какие драйвера стоят на вашей ОС 3. если у вас ноутбук, то может быть причина в работе от сети или от батареи. Возможно вы найдете ответ на ваш вопрос [здесь](https://codeby.net/threads/linux-visnet-namertvo.65431/).